# Entity not showing on api platform swagger

Tags: symfony4, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I am using api platform in my symfony project, but an entity is not showing int the api platform swagger.

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Please post your code so that others can help debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `@ApiResource()` like this exemple:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class MyEntity
{ }
```